# are row rank and column rank alway equal and no exceptions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Are there any cases when the row-rank and column rank of a matrix can not be equal? Or are they equal under all circumstances?

I understand the proof that they are equal but was wondering if there are any special cases when they are not equal.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I understand they are equal and also understand the basic idea/proof, but my question was if there exist a special case/matrix when they are not equal, thanks.

Comment: Check out the proof again What are the assumptions ? if one of the assumptions are not satisfied, the result will not hold in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are always equal. That's a basic theorem in Linear Algebra. You will find a proof [here](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/3004418139737.pdf.bannered.pdf), for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are always equal.

Row rank is equal to the number of non-zero rows in the RREF while the column rank is equal to the number of pivot columns in the RREF.